# Confusion about scope of variables with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How come myAdapter is visible to the onDataChange scope? other variables are not visible. I am confused as to when it is visible inside onDataChange and when not:

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ArrayList<User> myDataset;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   myDataset = new ArrayList<User>();
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);

 ValueEventListener listener= new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //doing stuff here, such as updating the data set


            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//<--how is it visible here? I thought its out of the async listener scope?

 }
```

For some variables I get that it's not in scope and I need to declare them `final`, and this `mAdapter`, and even `myDataset` are visible with no problems

Answer (score 2):

Local variables that you declare within `onCreateView` are only accessible within the `onDataChange` of the inner class if you declare them as final.

Member fields on the containing class are automatically visible within your inner class, and thus within its `onDataChange` method. The reason for this is that the compiler implicitly defines a `final` variable that refers to the outer object.